# PHP form keeps giving me back same response

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement, switch-statement

very short simple quiz app. browser keeps returning Correct as a response, even though it is not correct.

```
<?php
$answer = (isset($_POST['answer']));`
if ($answer == "Dagny Taggart")`
{
echo "Correct";
 } else {
 echo "wrong";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What's that extra tick mark for on lines 2 and 3: "`"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You're currently setting `$answer` to `isset($_POST['answer']`, meaning as long as `$_POST['answer']` is set, you're $answer is going to be `TRUE`. I would check if it's set and then set it to the `$_POST` value.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    if ($answer == "Dagny Taggart")
    {
        echo "Correct";
    } else {
        echo "wrong";
    }
} else {
// Do something?
}

?>
```

Comment: So what happens if `$_POST['answer']` isn't set in your example?

Comment: @Machavity They come back here and check my revised answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`isset` returns a boolean (`true` or `false`) value. So your test will always fail because `true` != 'Dagny Taggart'

Add this ternary and it will work

```
$answer = (isset($_POST['answer'])) ? $_POST['answer'] : '';
```